# SQL Server 2005 hashbytes(‘sha1’,'code') alternative in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, sql-server-2005, sha

Hi i have several passwords encrypted in this way:

```
hashbytes(‘sha1’,'password')
```

Using SQL Server 2005, we are planing a migration to MySQL.

There is a hash function equivalent in MySQL or PHP.

Because i use a standard SHA1 algorithm and results are different that the ones i have using SQL Server algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that php uses ascii encoding, so in order to get the same results in sql server management studio for example, use a varchar(8000) as @input.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a `SHA1` function:

```
mysql> SELECT SHA1('password');
+------------------------------------------+
| SHA1('password')                         |
+------------------------------------------+
| 5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8 |
+------------------------------------------+
```

What does the equivalent SQL Server function produce?

Comment: `DECLARE @HashThis nvarchar(MAX);  

SELECT @HashThis = 'password';  
SELECT HashBytes('SHA1', @HashThis);  `
  
returns 0xE8F97FBA9104D1EA5047948E6DFB67FACD9F5B73 which is different than 5baa61e4c9b93f3f0682250b6cf8331b7ee68fd8

Comment: To make this slightly easier to read - he got different hashes, but it was because he was using NVARCHAR instead of VARCHAR.  As per another post, you can use `sys.fn_varbintohexsubstring(0, HashBytes('SHA1', @HashThis), 1, 0)` to get an exact match... provided that @HashThis is varchar(8000)