# SQL function HASHBYTES does not exist

Tags: mysql, function

```
select HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'hi');
```

It should encode 'hi' but it just returns this error:

> [Exception, Error code 1,305, SQLState 42000] FUNCTION [dbName].HashBytes does not exist

I am using MySQL Database v5.7.22, mabye it is deprecated? Is there something else I should use or am I doing something wrong? Thanks

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HASHBYTES is only in sql server, you must have to find some other alternative of it in mysql
This answer can help [SQL Server 2005 hashbytes(‘sha1’,'code') alternative in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892462/sql-server-2005-hashbytes-sha1-code-alternative-in-mysql)